# Can't find variable Navigation inside onPress HeaderBackButton

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to override the **HeaderBackButton** and i have successfully done that but the issue is i am not able to **goBack** in **HeaderBackButton onPress**, I am unable to access navigation object inside onPress of the HeaderBackButton.

I am using this piece of code

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Operation Screen',
    headerLeft: (
        <HeaderBackButton
            onPress={ ()=>{
                    console.log('HeaderBackButton');
                    // Do some custom stuff
                    navigation.goBack();
                }}
        />
    )
};
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @GauravRoy it was can't find variable navigation, the solution given below works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define it as a function. You can have `navigation` as a parameter

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: 'Operation Screen',
        headerLeft: (
            <HeaderBackButton
                onPress={() => {
                        console.log('HeaderBackButton');
                        // Do some custom stuff
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```